# Error: invalid quantifier - RegExp within JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm attempting to use the following RegExp to validate a password entered into my form;

8-12 characters with at least 1 capital, 1 numeric character, 1 special character from @#$!&*

```
^(?=.*[\d])(?=.*[a-z])(?=*[A-Z])(?=*[@#$!&*]).{8,12}$
```

When I enter it into my JavaScript function, it throws error "invalid quantifier"

I'm pretty new to both JavaScript and RegExp, so this might be a pretty simple question, but if anyone has any advice on where I might be incorrect or misguided I'd appreciate it a lot!

Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

Your usage of `(?=* ... )` for the uppercase and special characters requirements are missing a character or metacharacter for the `*` quantifier to be applied to. In such patterns, as with your other examples, it should be a dot.

With this update, the complete pattern is:

```
^(?=.*[\d])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$!&*]).{8,12}$
```

Comment: Omg. Duh. Sorry, typos will be the death of me. Thanks!

Comment: @beckalyce no problem! As a side note, you can use `\d` instead of `[\d]` since it's redundant to include it in a character class by itself.

Answer (score 0):

A `*` needs to quantify something. Put something preceding it to quantify.